# Lua pattern replace uppercase letters

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, uppercase, lowercase, lua-patterns

I need a special Lua pattern that takes all the uppercase letters in a string, and replaces them with a space and the respective lowercase letter;

```
TestStringOne => test string one
this isA TestString => this is a test string
```

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming only ASCII is used, this works:

```
function lowercase(str)
  return (str:gsub("%u", function(c) return ' ' .. c:lower() end))
end

print(lowercase("TestStringOne"))
print(lowercase("this isA TestString"))
```

Comment: `%u` matches uppercase; `%l` for lowercase =)

Comment: @YuHao: You must have left something out (the ' ' .. ) as this does not take care of the added space requirement and in effect it is no different than simply str:lower().

Answer (score 2):

```
function my(s)
  s = s:gsub('(%S)(%u)', '%1 %2'):lower()
  return s
end

print(my('TestStringOne'))              -->test string one
print(my('this isA TestString'))        -->this is a test string
```

Comment: I'm just giving you another possibility.  He can keep the trophy :)